# How to maintain the number form in the next operation?

Tags: list-manipulation

I am dealing with coordinates of atoms, in which I need to control the number of decimals.

Take two sets of coordinates as an example:

```
PadRight[PadRight[{{4.440892098500626*^-16, 13.302150202128976`, -7.0545304592155516`},{6.949999999999999`,5.617618119215058`,2.2698604949790777`}},{2,4},1],{2,5},PT]
```

Above gives:

```
{{4.44089*10^-16, 13.3022, -7.05453, 1, PT}, {6.95, 5.61762, 2.26986, 1, PT}}
```

But, as this will be written as a line in a text file later, my target is:

```
{{0.00000,13.30200,-7.05450,1,PT},{6.95000,5.61760,2.26990,1,PT}}
```

So, I try this:

```
PadRight[PadRight[NumberForm[{{4.440892098500626*^-16, 
 13.302150202128976`, -7.0545304592155516`}, {6.949999999999999`, 
 5.617618119215058`, 2.2698604949790777`}}, {5, 5}, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)], {2, 4}, 1], {2, 5}, PT]
```

What I get is:

```
{{4.44090*10^(-16),13.30200,-7.05450},{6.95000,5.61760,2.26990},1.00000,1.00000,PT}.
```

How can I get the target number form in the final output?

Comment: Have you tried `NumberForm[Round[#, 10.^-5], {5, 5}] & /@ list`?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I need to Pad[] integers like 0,1 and element symbols like PT, O into the list. If I pad after NumberForm[], it still does not work. Finally I need to Export[] the list into a .txt file. And it is found that even if the right number form is obtained just before Export[], after exporting the number form is restored to the originally uncontrolled form. Is there a command to execute the number form during the whole process?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simple modified code

```
list = {{4.440892098500626*^-16, 13.302150202128976`, -7.0545304592155516`},
        {6.949999999999999`, 5.617618119215058`, 2.2698604949790777`}};

ToString@PadRight[ Map[ToString@NumberForm[Round[#, 10.^-5], {5, 5}] &,
   list, {2}], {2, 5}, {PT, 1}]
```

which returns the string result

```
{{0.00000, 13.30200, -7.05450, 1, PT}, {6.95000, 5.61760, 2.26990, 1, PT}}
```

is what you wanted and you can export the string to a text file.

Comment: It works! But I found I have to take the "ToString" off, maybe because later I have to write it line by line as: 
atoms = Join[ PadRight[Map[ToString@NumberForm[Round[#, 10.^-5], {5, 5}] &, Pt2L, {2}], {2 Length[b], 5}, {PT, 1}], PadRight[Map[ToString@NumberForm[Round[#, 10.^-5], {5, 5}] &, Au3L, {2}], {3 Length[B], 5}, {AU, 2}]] ATOMS = ReplacePart[atoms, Position[atoms, {"0.00000", "0.00000", "0.00000", 1, PT}] -> {0, 0, 0, 0, PT}] file = OpenAppend["x.txt"] string = ExportString[ATOMS, "CSV"]; WriteString[file, string] WriteString[file, "\n"]; Close[file]

Comment: Great!. I only put it in because I thought you wanted it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.

1. [`PadRight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight) should accept a list  as argument, not a [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm) object. So, you should put the [`PadRight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight) calls inside of [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm):

   ```
   paddedData = PadRight[
       PadRight[
           {
           {4.440892098500626*^-16,13.302150202128976`,-7.0545304592155516`},
           {6.949999999999999`,5.617618119215058`,2.2698604949790777`}
           },
           {2,4},
           1
       ],
       {2,5},
       PT
   ];

   NumberForm[paddedData, {5, 5}, ExponentFunction -> (Null&)]
   ```

   > {{0.00000,13.30200,-7.05450,1,PT},{6.95000,5.61760,2.26990,1,PT}}
2. Exporting to a text file. Contrary to what the documentation says, the export to a text file uses [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm), not [`OutputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OutputForm), and so explicit [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm) wrappers will appear:

   ```
   ExportString[
       NumberForm[
           paddedData,
           {5, 5},
           ExponentFunction -> (Null&)
       ],
       "Text"
   ]
   ```

   > "NumberForm[{{4.440892098500626*^-16, 13.302150202128976, \
   >   -7.0545304592155516, 1, PT}, {6.949999999999999, 5.617618119215058, \
   >   2.2698604949790777, 1, PT}}, {5, 5}, ExponentFunction -> (Null & )]"

   One way to work around this is to create a new wrapper that formats [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm) objects in [`OutputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OutputForm). So:

   ```
   Format[myNumberForm[args__], InputForm] := OutputForm[NumberForm[args]]
   ```

   Then:

   ```
   ExportString[
       myNumberForm[
           paddedData,
           {5, 5},
           ExponentFunction -> (Null&)
       ],
       "Text"
   ]
   ```

   > "{{0.00000, 13.30200, -7.05450, 1, PT}, {6.95000, 5.61760, 2.26990, 1, PT}}"

Comment: Woll sama, I got your good idea: 1) pad 2)myNumberForm 3)export. 

Two problems are: 
(1) I cannot use the ExportString[] for .txt as Wolfram outputs the error as "ExportString::format: /Users/binghu/Desktop/22.txt is not a recognized ExportString format". But I can turn to OpenAppend[] and WriteString[] to solve this problem. 
(2) I finally need to write the list of lists line by line, like:
 ATOMS
-25.02000,-14.44500,0.00000,1,PT
-23.63000,-12.03800,0.00000,1,PT
-22.24000,-9.63020,0.00000,1,PT

Comment: Use Export instead of ExportString. I used ExportString so you could see what the file would look like

Comment: Oh！That is right:D